# Goroutines with ListenAndServe increases performance?

Tags: concurrency, go

I'm not very familiar with Go's routines but since I'm working with the router of `net/http` I saw a few times that`ListenAndServe()` is wrapped by a go routine.

A server needs to be able to handle multiple requests simultaneously out of the box to be efficient. So why are go routines as 'lightweight threads' used?
Does the concurrency provide any advantages?

Here's an example by [OpenShift](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/67ef8497bbcd4f7ea8bc4e0e2daa75ba0c613f20/examples/hello-openshift/hello_openshift.go)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func helloHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello OpenShift!")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", helloHandler)

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("serving on 8080")
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
        if err != nil {
            panic("ListenAndServe: " + err.Error())
        }
    }()

    go func() {
        fmt.Println("serving on 8888")
        err := http.ListenAndServe(":8888", nil)
        if err != nil {
            panic("ListenAndServe: " + err.Error())
        }
    }()
    select {}
}
```

Comment: I believe that this is done simply so that the same program can listen on two ports, and not for performance, since `http.ListenAndServe` binds to a single port and then blocks.

Comment: Good idea but if you look [here](https://github.com/emmasteimann/filemonitor/blob/2d6dd37589b6a89a76d44700a94e68543fd1979b/filemonitor/filemonitor.go), [here](https://github.com/omniscale/imposm3/blob/0807c33eaaa5146d3f8088bf23e058524055c4fd/stats/http.go) and [here](https://github.com/oxfeeefeee/kaiju/blob/9e97515d5425f2eeb0c8070dec8ab054debce991/profiling/profiling.go) you'll see that the server only listens on a single port.

Comment: @Ezra is correct about the example listed, the [commit log](https://github.com/openshift/origin/commit/7719a17648413ee0775d00dedfaf5c94025f798c) for the change to this says "serve on multiple ports". In each of the other cases you gave, it is done is for the same reason: the call to `ListenAndServe` blocks, if you want/need to return you need to put it in a goroutine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`http.ListenAndServe` is a blocking call. If you want to go one doing more work (like making a second `http.ListenAndServe` call), you need to move it over to a separate goroutine. That's all they're doing here.

They're using `select{}` at the end to block the main goroutine, since all their calls to `http.ListenAndServe` are on other goroutines. If they didn't call `select{}`, the program would terminate because `main()` would return.

They could have achieved the same thing by dropping `select{}`, and removing the `go func()` wrapper around the last block of code. But I suspect they did it this way so that all the code is consistent.

But this has nothing to do with performance.

In the comments you provided some other examples that are similar. In the [first example](https://github.com/emmasteimann/filemonitor/blob/2d6dd37589b6a89a76d44700a94e68543fd1979b/filemonitor/filemonitor.go):

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", responsehandler.Handler)
    go func() {
      http.ListenAndServe(":8888", nil)
    }()
    fileservice.NewWatcher()
}
```

This calls `http.ListenAndServe` and then calls `fileservice.NewWatcher()` (which blocks). If they hadn't wrapped the call in a goroutine, `fileservice.NewWatcher()` would never have been called.

The other [two](https://github.com/omniscale/imposm3/blob/0807c33eaaa5146d3f8088bf23e058524055c4fd/stats/http.go) [examples](https://github.com/oxfeeefeee/kaiju/blob/9e97515d5425f2eeb0c8070dec8ab054debce991/profiling/profiling.go) are a common piece of boilerplate:

```
func init() {
    go func() {
        log.Println(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:6060", nil))
    }()
}
```

This turns on the debug profiler web server. Again, it's a goroutine so that calling `init` returns immediately rather than blocking. This particular case allows the caller to just `import _ "profiling"` and "magically" get the debug profiler web server.

Comment: Thanks for this extensive answer by commenting the examples. [Ezra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/640277/ezra)'s assumption was right.

Comment: @Rob This would work. But how to close the program gracefully. If i stop the program running this code won't there be go routine leak. How would you stop go func() ??

Comment: @DineshGowda When a process terminates, all goroutines are automatically destroyed. This is a feature of Unix; Go doesn't have to do anything here (and couldn't prevent it).

Comment: Oh I get it. Thanks. I thought there would be a go routine leak as we don't return from that routine call when so one stops the process.

Comment: From a standpoint of concurrency - can you explain, why it is safe to pass the same handler function to both the ListenandServe calls in the two separate go routines? Thank you!

Comment: @Weana I'm not quite certain what you mean here. What concurrency issue are you worried about? (Handler functions are just functions; if the function is thread-safe, then calling the function indirectly is safe in the same ways.)

Comment: Sure, thanks for your quick response. In the example above we have (at least) two separate go routines running. What does now happen, when two requests arrive on the two ports? Both go routines would now invoke the same handler. I am unfortunately not that deep into Go programming. But what happens now e.g. when the handler function accesses a package level (global) variable? Do we have two instances of the handler function running in parallel and is it not possible that those two try to access this P-L-variable concurrently? Or is this the specific definition of thread-safety, you mentioned?

Comment: "when the handler function accesses a package level (global) variable?"  A handler function must never do that without using some kind of exclusive access (a lock, another go routine). This is what I meant by "if the function is thread-safe."

Comment: Great, then I have understood the crucial point here. Thanks for clarification :)!

Answer (score 1):

No it does not have any special benefits beside being "run in the background".

Comment: What do you exactly mean with 'run in the background'

Comment: Run in its own goroutine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a go routine to start ListenAndServe. According to the Go Documentations.

"ListenAndServe calls Serve". Serve is  go routine.

ListenAndServe listens on the TCP network address addr and then calls Serve with handler to handle requests on incoming connections. Accepted connections are configured to enable TCP keep-alives. Handler is typically nil, in which case the DefaultServeMux is used.
https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe

func Serve(l net.Listener, handler Handler) error
Serve accepts incoming HTTP connections on the listener l, creating a new service goroutine for each. The service goroutines read requests and then call handler to reply to them. Handler is typically nil, in which case the DefaultServeMux is used.
https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Serve

Comment: No. The documentation talks about creating a goroutine per incoming connection. `ListenAndServe` is still a blocking call.